# SWIG - C++ to python - enum that has ULL values being converted to 0

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a legacy C++ code base that I am using SWIG to generate python bindings for.
In this code base there are enums all over that have specific values that are then used for binary operations.

A typical header file used looks something like this:

```cpp
namespace doom
{
class Bar
{
public:
    struct FooIdent
    {
        enum Ident
        {
            UnknownFoo = 0,
            KnownFoo = 1,
            MainFoo = 2,
            SecondaryFoo = 3
        };
    };

    enum FooPresence
    {
        Boo = 0x0,
        Foo1 = 0x8000000000ULL,
        Foo2 = 0x4000000000ULL,
        Foo3 = 0x2000000000ULL,
        FooWithA1 = 0x1000000000ULL,
        FooWithA2 = 0x0800000000ULL,
        FooWithA3 = 0x0400000000ULL,
        FooWithA4 = 0x0200000000ULL,
        FooWithB1 = 0x0100000000ULL,
        FooWithB2 = 0x0080000000,
        FooWithB3 = 0x0040000000
    };

    Bar();

    void setVesODee( int ves, doom::Bar::FooPresence pr );
    void setVesOGoo( int goo, doom::Bar::FooIdent::Ident ide );
    int doSomething();

private:
    int m_vdee;
    int m_vgoo;
};
} // namespace doom
```

The corresponding `.cpp` file would then be:

```
#include "bar.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace doom
{

Bar::Bar()
{
    m_vdee = 0;
    m_vgoo = 0;
}

void Bar::setVesODee( int ves, doom::Bar::FooPresence pr ) {
    m_vdee = static_cast< doom::Bar::FooPresence >( ves | pr );
}

void Bar::setVesOGoo( int goo, doom::Bar::FooIdent::Ident ide ) {
    m_vgoo = static_cast< doom::Bar::FooIdent::Ident >( goo | ide );
}

int Bar::doSomething() {
    return m_vgoo + m_vdee;
}

} // namespace doom


int main() {
    doom::Bar b = doom::Bar();

    b.setVesODee(3, doom::Bar::FooWithB2);
    b.setVesOGoo(4, doom::Bar::FooIdent::MainFoo);

    int c = b.doSomething();
    std::cout << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `.i` file would look something like this:

```
%feature ("flatnested");

%module bar

%{

#include "bar.h";

%}

%rename("Bar_%s", %$isnested) "";
%include "bar.h"
```

I build using the following commands:

```sh
swig -python -c++ -py3 bar.i
g++ -fPIC -c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) bar.cpp bar_wrap.cxx
g++ -shared -o _bar.so bar.o bar_wrap.o
```

And I then test the code using:

```py
import bar

for i in dir(bar.Bar_FooIdent):
    if i[0].isupper():
        print(f'{i} = 0x{getattr(bar.Bar_FooIdent, i):X}')

print()

for i in dir(bar.Bar):
    if i[0].isupper():
        print(f'{i} = 0x{getattr(bar.Bar, i):X}')
```

This outputs:

```
KnownFoo = 0x1
MainFoo = 0x2
SecondaryFoo = 0x3
UnknownFoo = 0x0

Boo = 0x0
Foo1 = 0x0
Foo2 = 0x0
Foo3 = 0x0
FooWithA1 = 0x0
FooWithA2 = 0x0
FooWithA3 = 0x0
FooWithA4 = 0x0
FooWithB1 = 0x0
FooWithB2 = 0x-80000000
FooWithB3 = 0x40000000
```

It seems to be that SWIG does not convert the ULL literals correctly, and I cannot figure out how to tell SWIG to interpret these as larger types.

I am not very comfortable using SWIG but I have been able to make do for a while now and am able to generate most of the code I need. I searched the documentation and questions online, but I have not been able to make this work. Any pointers for making this conversion happen?

Comment: Note that `enum FooPresence` defaults to using `int` as its type.  It should be `enum FooPresence : unsigned long long` if you want 64-bit integers in the enum.  I get compiler warnings of truncated integers compiling as shown.

Comment: When running `swig`  I see the warning message: `Warning 325: Nested struct not currently supported (FooIdent ignored)` so that explains why those enumerations aren't processed.

Comment: Warning message `enum FooPresence` (default int): `warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant value`

Comment: I thought this would be enough. I am sorry about the mess. I'm trying to modify and simplify (maybe way too much) the existing code. I'll get the example to the correct place without using my cmake build and extra `.i` imports up and running tomorrow. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have added all the necessary files and steps to reproduce the error. When I add your suggested typemap, I get `AttributeError: module '_bar' has no attribute 'Bar_Boo'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWIG by default treats enum constants as `int`, even if you override with:

```cpp
enum FooPresence : unsigned long long { ... }
```

This generates code in the `test_wrap.cxx` file like:

```cpp
SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "Foo1",SWIG_From_int(static_cast< int >(Foo1)));
SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "Foo2",SWIG_From_int(static_cast< int >(Foo2)));
```

I was able to get correct results by overriding the `constcode` typemap to assume 64-bit integers instead.

test.i

```cpp
%module test

%typemap(constcode) int %{SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "$1",PyLong_FromLongLong(static_cast<long long>($1)));%}

%inline %{
enum FooPresence : unsigned long long
{
    Foo1 = 0x8000000000ULL,
    Foo2 = 0x4000000000ULL,
    Foo3 = 0x2000000000ULL,
    FooWithA1 = 0x1000000000ULL,
    FooWithA2 = 0x0800000000ULL,
    FooWithA3 = 0x0400000000ULL,
    FooWithA4 = 0x0200000000ULL,
    FooWithB1 = 0x0100000000ULL,
    FooWithB2 = 0x0080000000,
    FooWithB3 = 0x0040000000
};
%}
```

You can see the SWIG typemap matching search by using the `-debug-tmsearch` flag when building.  Note that it is searching for `int Foo1` and not `enum FooPresence` or `long long Foo1`:

```
C:\test>swig -c++ -python -debug-tmsearch test.i
test.i(8) : Searching for a suitable 'consttab' typemap for: int Foo1
  Looking for: int Foo1
  Looking for: int
  Looking for: SWIGTYPE Foo1
  Looking for: SWIGTYPE
  None found
test.i(8) : Searching for a suitable 'constcode' typemap for: int Foo1
  Looking for: int Foo1
  Looking for: int
  Using: %typemap(constcode) int
...
```

Demo:

```py
>>> import test
>>> hex(test.Foo1)
'0x8000000000'
>>> hex(test.FooWithA1)
'0x1000000000'
```

Comment: Maybe I can be clearer. After adding the typemap, the enums that were accessible before (although with wrong values), are no longer accessible and I encounter an AttributeError on import time from the modules that contained those enums. Is it because `SWIG_Python_SetConstant` is setting the attribute with the nested name (e.g. 'Bar::Foo') onto the `PyObject`? I am wondering where the magic from before went wrong.

Comment: Ok. I was not correct in my previous assumption. The problem I have now is that there are not all enums inside a struct in the source code, some are in the namespace of the class, and those enums are causing problems at import time. Other enums, that are inside a struct inside the class, do appear in the dir output of the `.so` file.

Comment: @hoboman Edit your question with a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: I have updated the code to hopefully represent the problem better.

Comment: After browsing some old lecture notes online and rereading the documentation, I came back to your answer and used it with a minor change: "$1" to "$symname" which made it work. Thank you again for all your help. If you update the answer I can hit the accept, or is that not how this site works?