# SWIG - OverflowError when methods have enum typed arguments

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ code base which uses SWIG to generate Python 3 interfaces.

I had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71125138/swig-c-to-python-enum-that-has-ull-values-being-converted-to-0) where I couldn't convert `enum` values into large enough types. This was solved with good help.

Now I have a new problem that relates to the other one. Methods that take the corrected `enum` values as arguments are throwing an `OverflowError` when the largest `enum` values are passed in as an argument.

I was wondering if there is a generic way to solve this using the `typemap` function (like the way with the enum objects). To identify all methods that take the `enum` constants as arguments. Or do I need to define an `in` `typemap` for each of the `enum` types?

What I have tried, and works, is including this in the `.i` file:

```
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply unsigned long long { doom::Bar::FooPresence };
```

But it would be great if there was a "catch all" kind of thing, like with the `constcode` typemap.

The code necessary to reproduce the current behavior:

`bar.h`

```cpp
namespace doom
{
class Bar
{
public:
    struct FooIdent
    {
        enum Ident
        {
            UnknownFoo = 0,
            KnownFoo = 1,
            MainFoo = 2,
            SecondaryFoo = 3
        };
    };

    enum FooPresence
    {
        Boo = 0x0,
        Foo1 = 0x8000000000ULL,
        Foo2 = 0x4000000000ULL,
        Foo3 = 0x2000000000ULL,
        FooWithA1 = 0x1000000000ULL,
        FooWithA2 = 0x0800000000ULL,
        FooWithA3 = 0x0400000000ULL,
        FooWithA4 = 0x0200000000ULL,
        FooWithB1 = 0x0100000000ULL,
        FooWithB2 = 0x0080000000,
        FooWithB3 = 0x0040000000
    };

    Bar();

    void setVesODee( int ves, doom::Bar::FooPresence pr );
    void setVesOGoo( int goo, doom::Bar::FooIdent::Ident ide );
    int doSomething();

private:
    int m_vdee;
    int m_vgoo;
};
} // namespace doom
```

`bar.cpp`

```cpp
#include "bar.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace doom
{

Bar::Bar()
{
    m_vdee = 0;
    m_vgoo = 0;
}

void Bar::setVesODee( int ves, doom::Bar::FooPresence pr ) {
    m_vdee = static_cast< doom::Bar::FooPresence >( ves & pr );
}

void Bar::setVesOGoo( int goo, doom::Bar::FooIdent::Ident ide ) {
    m_vgoo = static_cast< doom::Bar::FooIdent::Ident >( goo & ide );
}

int Bar::doSomething() {
    return m_vgoo + m_vdee;
}

} // namespace doom


int main() {
    doom::Bar b = doom::Bar();

    b.setVesODee(3, doom::Bar::FooWithB2);
    b.setVesOGoo(4, doom::Bar::FooIdent::MainFoo);

    int c = b.doSomething();
    std::cout << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`bar.i`

```cpp
%module bar

%feature ("flatnested");

%{
#define SWIG

#include "bar.h"

#define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR
%}


%typemap(constcode) int %{
    SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "$symname", PyLong_FromLongLong(static_cast<long long>($1)));
%}

%rename("Bar_%s", %$isnested) "";
%include "bar.h"
```

`test_bar.py`

```py
import bar

b = bar.Bar()
b.setVesODee(10, bar.Bar.Foo1)
```

`build-and-test.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Cleanup..."
rm -rf __pycache__
rm -f _bar.so bar.o bar_wrap.*

echo "Building..."
swig -python -c++ -py3 -debug-tmsearch bar.i
g++ -fPIC -c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) bar.cpp bar_wrap.cxx
g++ -shared -o _bar.so bar.o bar_wrap.o

echo "Testing..."
python3 test_bar.py
```

`output`

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_bar.py", line 15, in <module>
    b.setVesODee(10, bar.Bar.Foo1)
  File "/workspace/ctmp/bar.py", line 83, in setVesODee
    return _bar.Bar_setVesODee(self, ves, pr)
OverflowError: in method 'Bar_setVesODee', argument 3 of type 'doom::Bar::FooPresence'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SWIGTYPE` is the default type match when a type-specific match is not found.  You can use the following to apply to all enumerations:

```
%apply unsigned long long { enum SWIGTYPE };
```

See [13.3.3 Default typemap matching rules](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn19) in the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html).

Example:

test.i

```cpp
%module test

%typemap(constcode) int %{SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "$1",PyLong_FromLongLong(static_cast<long long>($1)));%}
%apply unsigned long long { enum SWIGTYPE };

%{
#include <iostream>
%}

%inline %{
enum FooPresence : unsigned long long
{
    Foo1 = 0x8000000000ULL,
};

void func(FooPresence x) {
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned long long>(x) << std::dec << std::endl;
}

%}
```

Demo:

```py
>>> import test
>>> test.func(test.Foo1)
8000000000
```